# How to know if a specific program is supported in 14.04 when it is working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I am using 12.04 LTS and deciding whether to upgrade to 14.04.01 as the system upgrades keeps prompting me. So far, i had always indicated "Inform me later"

My main concern is how do i be sure that the programs that i am using now in 12.04, is supported in 14.04??

Is there a place to check? If yes, I have quite a few important programs (maybe 20+ in 12.04) and whats the effective way to check instead of one by one?

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: If it is in the 14.04 repositories it is supported.

Comment: Hi bodhi, can i know where (URL) can I find the 14.04 repositories in order for me to manually check? Thank you

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search feature at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to see if a package exists in a given version of Ubuntu.

In almost all cases a package will continue to be available, it'd be rare that a package is removed completely.